# OCaml - setting reference to next node in inorder (binary tree)

Tags: ocaml, inorder

type 'a tree= | Empty| Node of 'a * 'a tree* 'a tree* 'a tree ref;;

We would like to set for every node tree ref to next node in inorder;

For example

```
Node (1, Node(2, Empty, Empty, ref Empty), Node(3, Empty, Empty, ref Empty), ref Empty) )
The result is:

Node (1, Node(2, Empty, Empty, content = {Node (1....) }).....
```

Comment: It's hard to help without ruining the assignment, unless you show us some code you've written and explain why and how it doesn't do what you want. As a general hint, I'd say this calls for a fold. You have to decide what to do for the last node.

Comment: I really suggest you to learn ocaml and functional programming. I guess your boss asked you to use ocaml to achieve something, but your java imperative gut leads you to evil. Please, just learn.

Comment: How to use a fold in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not hard: you do an inorder traversal, while passing around (and
returning) the reference contained in the previous node. When you get
to a given node, you set the reference of the previous node to the
current node. If each node is assigned to the reference of the previous
one, that means every node's reference contains the next node.

On the example, the inorder traversal goes through the tree in this
order: 2 1 3

When you are at node 2, you return its ref to the caller, which is
node 1. When you arrive at node 1, you set the ref of node 2 to
point to node 1, and you pass the ref of node 1 to node 3. When
you are at node 3, you set the ref of node 1 to point to node 3.

You need to decide what to do for the first node (allocate a dummy
reference to start the process) and the last node (presumably, set
its reference to Empty, although sometimes it might be useful to
set it to the first node).

I have working code (15 lines). I won't post it because that would
spoil the presumed assigment.